# Does routing work after adding ngLoadScript as dependency inside app.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have added revolution slider inside ngview to load the slides I had to add ngLoadScript as dependency and script type as `type="text/javascript-lazy"` and when I'm trying to route view isn't loaded.

```
 angular
        .module("SaltApp", [
            'ngLoadScript','ngRoute'
        ])
        .run(run)
        .config(config);

function config($routeProvider) {

                $routeProvider
                .when("/", { 
                templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
            })
            .when('/product',{
                templateUrl:"partials/product.html"
                // controller:"detailsController"
            })

            .when('/blog',{
                templateUrl:"partials/blog.html"
                // controller:"detailsController"
            })
}
```

Need the pages to be loaded fast which are inside partials.